# Custom http Logs Haproxy

Tags: haproxy

Hi I am trying to configure Custom logging for my Haproxy version 1.4.22. I am using option httplog and option asap when I add

```
  log format %hr\ %r\ %st\ %B\ %Tr
```

in listen section I get below error

```
  service haproxy restart
  [ALERT] 288/112904 (14449) : parsing [/etc/haproxy/haproxy.cfg:46] : unknown log    facility '%hr %r %st %B %Tr'
```

Errors found in configuration file, check it with 'haproxy check'.

I would like to know where should I put directive log format in my haproxy config file.
Any help will be appreciated .

Answer (score 2):

The directive should be `log-format`, not `log format`. However, custom log formats aren't available in 1.4.x; you'd need to upgrade to 1.5 in order to use that.

Comment: I got same error [ALERT] 288/120615 (14468) : parsing [/etc/haproxy/haproxy.cfg:46] : unknown keyword 'log-format' in 'listen' section
[ALERT] 288/120615 (14468) : Error(s) found in configuration file : /etc/haproxy/haproxy.cfg
[ALERT] 288/120615 (14468) : Fatal errors found in configuration.
Errors found in configuration file, check it with 'haproxy check'.

Comment: Sorry, I missed which version you're using. Custom log formats were only introduced in version 1.5, so they don't work in 1.4.22. I'll amend my answer to clarify that.

Comment: I even tried that with HaProxy version 1.5 but no luck.